# how to do formatting by grouping some columns by pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

`df.pivot_table(index=[["Id"+"layer"],['S1', 'S2', 'S3]],columns="Date",values=['S1', 'S2', 'S3]`

use this code but error is coming

there are a lot of columns in Data frame. How can I do grouping so that I can easily recognize all data.
[input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6kyT.png)

[output data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaECR.png)

Comment: please add your data as text to your question, NOT as images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please paste the complete error message

Comment: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: plz help really need this code